# Как подключиться к удаленному серверу через Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Вопрос такой - я подключаюсь к удаленному серверу через Ubuntu, как мне подключиться к нему через Visual Studio Code? При попытке подключения через VSC пишет: Permission denied (publickey).
Надо использовать ключ сгенерированный на Ubuntu?

Comment: Вы предоставили слишком мало информации. Есть десятки способов "подключиться"

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Есть плагин SFTP

Comment: Находясь на Ubuntu я сгенерерировал ssh-ключи и подключился к удаленному серверу. Теперь мне необходимо подключиться к этому серверу через Visual Studio Code. Я набираю в VSC команду ssh username@server с которой успешно подключался через Ubuntu, в ответ получаю: "Permission denied (publickey)"